# TYPO3 Extension ke_search, dont index my tt_content fluidcontent

Tags: typo3

I can't figure out why ke_cearch does not index my content elements
Prompt if someone came across.
http://prnt.sc/mr8qs9

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dx4nL.png)

myconfig

[http://prnt.sc/mr8umx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXl5L.png)

But defolt fluidcontent texrmedia or text indexes great

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a custom indexer for this.

Take a look here: https://www.typo3-macher.de/en/facetted-search-ke-search/documentation/write-your-own-custom-indexer/